# Compare form data against database and perform an action

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I have a website where the user must already exist in the database to be able to proceed to the next page. I have made a query that checks their first name, last name, and email address against those stored in the DB and I can get it to print the result if they match, but I can't get it to return a true or something I can work with in order to perform an action. I need to send an email to the user then redirect them to another page, could you help out with this too?

Here's my code

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");

$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

$connect = $conn; 
if (!$connect) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Prepare the statement
$stid = oci_parse($connect, "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname' AND email = '$email'");

if (!$stid) {
    $e = oci_error($connect);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Perform the logic of the query
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stid);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Fetch the results of the query
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($connect);

?>
```

If you could please help me to run an action if true (send an email and redirect) and display an error if the user does not exist in the database. Thanks - I'm very new to PHP

Comment: Well, if the result of your database query isnt null or 0 you can proceed to the next page?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php to check for the number of rows. If the count is 1 (or greater) run your actions. If 0 display an error messaage.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you get the information out of the database, why don't you compare them to the given user inputs? If they match you can set a variable to true. Simply push the data that you get from the query in variables.

Comment: Sorry I'm actually so bad at programming and don't even know how to do it :l

Comment: I've tried to run an if statement on $stid but it doesn't work, where do I compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with multiple solutions.
I will give you two recommendations.
The first one is to use a SQL select that counts the returning rows of an executed query.
Try this:

SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE SURNAME LIKE '%surname%' AND NAME LIKE '%name%' AND EMAIL like '%email%'

Execute this and after the execute command insert this:
echo oci_num_rows($stid) . " people with this data.\n";

If it is 1 you have somebody with this data in your database.

You can also use JavaScript. If you want I can explain that also.
EDIT: here you go with pure javascript:

```
A short example of comparasion in JS
http://jsfiddle.net/marcusrommel/tcm4ak1p/
```

Comment: I'm a bit more comfortable with Javascript, could you please explain it with Js?

Comment: i added a link to a jsfiddle.